# How to use exist database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a exist web application build by PHP.

Now i need to rebuild this application by Rails.

I already have this following data in database:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| user_id | user_name         | .....             
--------------------------------------------------
| 1       | david             | .....
--------------------------------------------------
| 2       | jobs              | .....
--------------------------------------------------
```

I use this following command to generate User model:

```
rails g model User
```

And i type columns into User migration file manually:

```
 create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :user_name
      ...
      ...
      t.timestamps
end
```

Then i try to use following command to read data:

```
@users = User.first
```

But it throw me an error, It show me should use **rake db:migrate** to generate table.

So i think i should export my data and use **rake db:migrate** to build my database structure, And import my data.

It's a little bother for a few table.

But, Actually i have too many tables (about 54), So i must write the 54 migrations manually.

> So, is there a easy way to use exist database?

BTW, i use rails4

Answer (score 0):

You could just dump your tables to `schema.rb`:

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

then convert it to your initial migration (`001_initial_migration.rb`):

```
class InitialMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    # put whole schema.rb here
  end

  def self.down
    # drop everything
  end
end
```

You don't need to write 54 migrations, one big one is enough.

There is also [rmre gem](https://github.com/bosko/rmre), which tries to write your models for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I use rails4, The migration file seems only contain **change** method, there is no **up** and **down** method. and the **rmre gem** is only stand by Rails3

Answer (score 0):

you need not write migration for existed table,only write model for existed table,for example:

```
class User < AR
 self.table_name = "users" # your existed table name in db
 # attr_accessible :attrs
 # Associations,remember indicate :foreign_key 
end
```

if you want to add new table, do it as usual